# Local extrema of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

If a polynomial has the distinct (real) roots, say $a$ and $b$, with $a<b$, then we know it will have a local extremum between $a$ and $b$. Here, I am referring to the case where there are no other zeros between $a$ and $b$, but feel free to comment on the case where there are. Can anyone give a quick example to show that this local extremum is not always located at the midpoint of $a$ and $b$, and can someone describe the cases where it is located at the midpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a polynomial ($\ne 0$), and $n$ its degree.

First of all, let's consider $n = 2$, and $P$ with two real roots, that we will call $a$ and $b$. In this case, if we call $c$ the extremum of $P$, we do have:
$$c = \dfrac{a+b}{2}$$.
That's because $P(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$, for some $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb R$, (and with $\Delta = \beta^2 - 4 \alpha\gamma \ge 0$), implies that $a = \dfrac{-\beta + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2\alpha}$ and $b = \dfrac{-\beta - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2\alpha}$.

Then, the maximum is such that $P'(c) = 0$ i.e. $2 \cdot \alpha c + \beta = 0 \iff c = -\dfrac{\beta}{2\alpha}$. And we have:

$$\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \left(a + b\right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\dfrac{-\beta + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2\alpha} + \dfrac{-\beta - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2\alpha}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\dfrac{-2\beta}{2\alpha}\right) = -\dfrac{\beta}{2\alpha} = c$$
So $c$ is indeed the midpoint of the roots when $n = 2$.

But this does not hold for $n > 2$. We can take for example $P(x) = (x- 1)(x  - 2)(x - 3) = x^3 - 6 x^2 + 11 x - 6$. The roots are $1, 2, 3$, but if we take $a = 2$ and $b = 3$, the minimum between these two roots is $2 + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt3} \ne \dfrac{2 + 3}{2}$.